# Pandas - Tokenizing Data Expected 1 field saw multiple

Tags: python, pandas

A bit confused why I am getting this error. I thought skiprows should have taken care of me.

Error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 13
```

Line:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv(infile.name, skiprows=[6], sep=',')
```

CSV:

```
Header: 1asdf
Header: 2fac
Header: 3aaz
Header: 4ssw
Header: 5aaa
0.0,-64,192,152,27023,3,0,26275,31473,149,67,77,0.0
0.04050016403198242,-64,192,148,27021,3,0,26274,31471,149,67,77,0.038919925689697266
0.08100008964538574,-64,192,148,27017,3,0,26275,31467,149,67,77,0.07783985137939453
0.12150001525878906,-60,192,148,27019,3,0,26277,31467,149,67,77,0.1167600154876709
0.16199994087219238,-60,192,144,27015,3,0,26277,31463,149,67,77,0.15567994117736816
0.2025001049041748,-60,192,148,27075,3,0,26319,31463,149,67,77,0.19460034370422363
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a list to skiprows, it interprets it as 'skip the rows in this list (0 indexed)'.  Pass an integer instead.  You probably also want `header=None` so your first row of data doesn't become the column names.

```
pd.read_csv(infile.name, skiprows=6, header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks @chrisb. This worked perfectly.

I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean when you say it's interpreting [n] as "skip the rows in this list". When would I use this method instead?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error message. In my case it was because commas were used as decimal marks and the cells were seperated by semicolon. In my case  `sep=";"` solved the problem:
`pd.read_csv(infile.name, sep=";")`

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you have more columns entries than specified in schema.

> That means - In your particulate column you should have delimiter in
>   it.

In this way interpreter assumes that new column is coming but in reality we dont have any so the exception is thrown as runtime.

Solution for that:

1. Best one is, ask your input source generator to solve this.
2. Second would be, if you have permission to skip the records then
   using this -

   df = pd.read_csv(file_loc, sep=',', keep_default_na=False)